# Warning when approaching a CLLocationCoordinate2D - how?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a way, to get a notification/warning, whenever I'm approaching a certain location.

I'm using a locationManager for receiving new locations as-i-go, and i have an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D-objects. I want to be informed when i'm getting close to one of those objects - say 10 meters or so.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to work this out yourself? What step specifically, do you not know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html):

Create a new **CLLocation** Object:

```
- initWithLatitude:longitude:
```

To determine the distance use:

```
– distanceFromLocation:
```

Im not familiar with your code, but this example will push you in the right direction:

```
CLLocation* firstLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:53.481508 longitude:33.398438];
CLLocation* secondLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-13.678013 longitude:-46.40625];

CLLocationDistance distance = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation];
if(distance < 10.00){
    NSLog(@"Distance is smaller than 10 meters");
}
```